# Image Class MF216n

Tags: drivers, canon

I'm trying to add Canon MF216n printer to my Linux computer. The driver is not listed in System Settings and the driver I got from Canon is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I would suggest by starting what release of Ubuntu (or flavor) you are using. Was the 'driver' you got from Canon for the release you are using?  (the more details [eg. site you got it from] you provide, the greater the chance we can help you)